# Parsing n lines to count vowels - HackerEarth

Tags: beginner, strings, programming-challenge, haskell, recursion

I have written a haskell program for the following 'Code Monk' Challenge at [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/).
Here is the [challenge description](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/linear-search/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-takes-a-walk/). Basically, we are looking for the number of vowels in a string. The first input n is the number of string to parse, followed by n number of random strings.

And here is my implementation:

```
import Data.Char
main = do
    numberOfTestCases <- getLine
    processLine (read numberOfTestCases :: Int)

processLine 0 = return()
processLine n = do
    line <- getLine
    print $ countVowels line
    processLine (n-1)

countVowels :: String -> Int
countVowels line = length $ filter (`elem` ['a','e','i','o','u']) $ map toLower line
```

My code is working correctly but as I'm fairly new to functional programming and Haskell I would like some comments about my code. More specifically, I would like the `processLine` function to not have a side effect, but I don't know how can I do that. Any other tips or comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Type signatures

You should add type signatures to *all* top-level bindings. `processLine`'s returned value and `main` should have the same type, which can be checked with the type checker, *if* you add type signatures. The following code would compile, since `main` will have the type `IO Int`:

```
processLine 0 = return 0
```

But that's not what you've intended. Therefore, make sure to add type-signatures to all your top-level bindings:

```
main :: IO ()
main = …

processLine :: Int -> IO ()
processLine n = …
```

By the way, `processLine`'s type signature makes `n`'s type unambigous, and therefore you don't need an explicit type in `(read numberOfTestCases :: Int)` anymore.

## Use syntactic sugar

`['a','e','i','o','u']` is `"aeiou"`, which is easier to change and to read (in my opionion). That way, we get:

```
countVowels :: String -> Int
countVowels line = length $ filter (`elem` "aeiou") $ map toLower line
```

By the way, if you use `"aeiouAEIOU"`, you don't need to import `Data.Char`.

## Keeping things pure(?)

> More specifically, I would like the processLine function to not have a side effect, but I don't know how can I do that.

At *some* point, you need to read the line. You've chosen `processLine` to do so. Note that it is not feasible to remove `IO` from `processLine`, because you would end up with `processLine = countVowels`.

Still, we can have a look at `processLine` to see what we can do. We can read the code literally:

1. If `n` is 0, do nothing
2. If `n` is greater than zero, do

   1. read a line
   2. count the vowels of the line
   3. print the number of vowels
   4. call `processLine` with `n` decreased by one

Or we can interpret it as

1. repeat the following action `n` times:

   1. read a line
   2. count the vowels of the line
   3. print the number of vowels
2. return nothing

If we have a look at the modules in `base`, we'll notice that `Control.Monad` contains `replicateM_`, which does exactly the "repeat-n-times"-part:

```
processAllLines :: Int -> IO ()
processAllLines n = replicateM_ n processSingleLine

processSingleLine :: IO () 
processSingleLine = do
    line <- getLine
    print $ countVowels line
```

Note that `processSingleLine` can get shortened into `getLine >>= print . countVowels`, but I'm not sure whether you're ready for that yet.

## Keeping things actually pure

Alright, we've seen how one could use standard functions to process all those lines. But it's still in `IO`. Can't we do anything?

Well, what would the alternative be? We still need to process a bunch of lines. A "bunch of something" can be easily expressed with a list, so let us write the type signature of our potential candidate.

```
processList :: [String] -> [Int]
```

The implementation comes rather easy:

```
processList = map countVowels
```

Now we just need to get a list of strings. Since we now want to get something from the user, we *have to* use `IO`:

```
getUserLines :: Int -> IO [String]
```

Seems familiar, doesn't it? "repeat-an-action-n-times". This time, it's `getLine`. Since we don't want to throw the result away, we use `replicateM` (note the missing `_`):

```
getUserLines n = replicateM n getLine
```

We're now missing two last ingredients. First, we need to print a list of `Int` so that the challenged site accepts it:

```
printSolutions :: [Int] -> IO ()
```

**Exercise:** write `printSolution`. Note that there is a function that might help you in the process.

We end up with the following `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  numberOfTestCases <- readLn
  userLines         <- getUserLines numberOfTestCases
  printSolutions (processList userLines)
```

## Further remarks

Search some of the `base` modules whether they provide the functions you're looking for. And have a look at `Prelude`. You've used `read` after `getLine`, which is provided as a single function `readLn` (see above).

For completion, here's how I would (probably) solve the challenge:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  numberOfTest <- readLn
  replicateM_ numberOfTest $ getLine >>= print . countVowels

countVowels :: String -> Int
countVowels xs = length $ filter (`elem` "aeuioAEUIO") xs
```

Comment: I just wanted to thank you, I won't have the time to check your answer until this evening, but it's seems that you have gone above and beyond to help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I learned a lot with your answer. Like, as much as a book really. It's great! Thanks!